# How do I get cmake to use my Homebrew installation of llvm exclusively?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, homebrew

My goal is to alias my cmake command so that it uses my homebrew installation of llvm exclusively, and not the suite installed by Xcode. I would like to leave the system defaults as defaults as well. I am on Catalina with Xcode and homebrew llvm up to date.

My first step is to use the homebrew clang++ and libc++, and I can do it manually

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ \
-nostdinc++ -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1 \
-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib \
main.cc
```

For completion's sake, here's my CMakeLists.txt; it's pretty barebones as most of the work I want to do doesn't belong in CMakeLists.txt and I'm just trying to compile a toy program.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(test
               main.cc)
```

But I'm already stuck with cmake here. I can specify the compiler using
`-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++` and similar for C/clang. I am using the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as well, but when I open my `build.ninja` files, I still see it referencing Xcode directories. Adding a `CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH` didn't seem to get it to actually ignore /Applications/Xcode.app.

I have also tried adding the flags `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` to my cmake command, but if I do this I start to get linker errors (still using the system linker and not homebrew's ld64.lld, I believe).

Here is my current working cmake command as a reference:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm" \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++" \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang" -G Ninja ..
```

The specific compiler paths are still required because cmake just breezes straight to AppleClang.

I know that the path repetition is annoying, but I want a full command to work before I start modifying my .zshrc.

Here's the broken command (broken as in building the program no longer succeeds, cmake doesn't complain here):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_IGNORE_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm" \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++" \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang" \
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES="/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib" \
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES="/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1" \
-G Ninja ..
```

With the build error message:

```
[2/2] Linking CXX executable test
FAILED: test 
: && /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cc.o  -o test  /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib && :
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib' for architecture x86_64
clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The variable `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` just gets ignored, so it's not included.

If anyone has any guidance, I would appreciate it. All links I have found about this usually override the system defaults, and I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: What happens if you try to compile and link manually using Homebrew's version of LLVM, so without using cmake?

Comment: If I add `fuse-ld="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/ld.lld"` to the compile command, I get a lot of other linker errors. Same if I try to use `ld64.lld`, although the latter provides less errors. I've never really invoked the linker manually, so while I can see that the errors are complaining about certain flags, I don't know how to fix them. And it appears I can't escape Xcode completely, as one error refers to not finding an SDK. This also probably goes to homebrew's take on not replacing system defaults. I may have to settle for the compilers and libc++ from homebrew. 1/2

Comment: I can force libc++ through `CXX_FLAGS` instead of those cmake variables. 2/2

Comment: Please try compiling without linking by using `clang -c`. To see the how the flags the compiler driver is invoked with use the `-###` flag. Do you see XCode specific flags other then `-isysroot`?

Comment: `-internal-isystem`, but it appears twice, once with Xcode stuff then immediately again followed by the homebrew llvm include directory. And then there's an `-internal-externc-isystem` that references Xcode stuff. I'm thinking I can clear that up by including `-nostdinc` along with my `-nostdinc++` flags.